# Discord.py while True loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I try to update multiple messages sent from the bot in a while true loop with a 15minutes sleep

```
@commands.cooldown(1, 30, commands.BucketType.user)
@bot.command()
async def updater(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Title")
    
    msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    all_stock.append(msg)

    while True:
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Title")
        await msg.edit(embed=embed)
        time.sleep(900)
```

but as soon as I run the function other commands don't work anymore. I already tried to create a separate thread but it didn't worked because of some async issues.

Comment: You have to run it as its own thread.

Comment: already tried it but it doesnt work because of async

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other commands don't work because `time.sleep` is blocking, you should use `asyncio.sleep` instead

```py
import asyncio

while True:
    # ...
    await asyncio.sleep(900)
```